# Angular 4 HttpClient Progress Event how to track each percentage in runtime

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic3, httpclient, progress

PS: **I edited this question because it was marked duplicated. So this is a new question that is different from the given duplicated question.**

I have a **provider** in Ionic that will handle all my API request to the **server**. On each **post/get/patch/delete** request or basically the **CRUD** operations. I want to perform an [ProgressEvent](https://angular.io/guide/http#listening-to-progress-events) on that **http operation** to track the progress percentage of the request. So basically I will have an stream of data of that percentage.

Here is the code that I have below:

```
publishEbook(data) {
const req = new HttpRequest('POST', `${url}/someApiEndpoint`, data, {
  reportProgress: true
});

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.http.request(req).subscribe((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
    switch (event.type) {
      case HttpEventType.Sent:
        console.log('Request sent!');
        break;
      case HttpEventType.ResponseHeader:
        console.log('Response header received!');
        break;
      case HttpEventType.UploadProgress:
        const percentDone = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
        console.log(`Posting in progress! ${ percentDone }%`);
        console.log(`Event: ${event.loaded}`);
        break;
      case HttpEventType.Response:
        console.log(' Done!', event.body);
        resolve(data);
    }
  }, err => {
    console.log(err);
    reject(err)
  });
});
```

}

The problem is I always get **100%** when connected to the internet and `NaN` when offline or because the http call is so fast it can't be intercept it's value? Is it still possible?

This is the line of code to determine the **progress percentage** of the http operation below:

```
const percentDone = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
```

So how do I track the progress percentage from **0, 1, 2, 50 to 100%** or a listener that gets called whenever a new chunk of data is passed in and get the percentage?

I already tried [angular-progress-http](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-progress-http) but can't find anything. I also tried [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) with the help of [Native API of JavaScript progressEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ProgressEvent) base on this [issue](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/629) and has the same result.

Will I create an observable for this and listen to the stream of data? But how?

Appreciate if someone could help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi do you have any progress on this topic? I'm also looking if it is possible to track the http request progress

Comment: @Huiting hit there. Unfortunately no. But I used [this](https://github.com/aitboudad/ngx-loading-bar) loading bar that automatically tracks each http request progress. I need to still track the progress of the http request percentage value which still I am looking for.

Comment: @Huiting hi check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51145141/how-to-know-the-request-progress-in-each-http-request-in-ionic-and-angular) out

Comment: @Huiting welcome! Happy to help.